# How to show an absolutely positioned sibling div on hover using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid of images with accompanying info in a sibling div that needs to show when the image is hovered over, then disappear when the cursor is off the image. I've looked at several similar questions here but none really have worked for what I need exactly.

It's for a site I've inherited that uses a different JS library that I'm switching to jQuery but I'm having a tough time figuring this out as I'm still learning jQuery.

I've set up the HTML & CSS here: http://jsfiddle.net/EQ2fG/

There's a screenshot of what I need here: http://cl.ly/JZkK

So on hover, the sibling div (.property_info) needs to display to the right of the image div (.property), but the ones for the last two in each row need to display to the left so it stays within the container/wrapper div. Keep in mind that the data will be dynamically generated.

I hope that makes sense. Any help would be really, really helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: You seem to be using the same id names on multiple elements. This isn't possible and could mess up your JQuery code,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with a combo of CSS(3) and jQuery - thanks to both folks who replied; I just needed a push in the right direction.

http://jsfiddle.net/angieherrera/EQ2fG/46/

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your code, you shouldn't have the same ID on multiple elements.
However, I think this should work:

```
$(".property").mouseover(function(){
    var wid=$(this).outerWidth();
    var left=$(this).position().left+wid;
    if(left+wid*2>$(this).parent().width())left=$(this).position().left-wid*2;
    var top=$(this).position().top;
    $(".prop_info").hide();
    $(".prop_info").eq($(".property").index($(this))).show().css({"opacity":1,"left":left,"top":top});
});
$("#property_grid").mouseout(function(){
    $(".prop_info").hide();
});
```

​
EDIT:
To make it stay visible when hovering over, change the mouseout to mouseleave and set the height of the property_grid so that it tightly wraps the content.

JS:

```
$("#property_grid").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".prop_info").hide();
});​
```

CSS:

```
#property_grid {
    width: 959px;
    height: 182px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Good catch on the same ID - was a leftover from too much copying & pasting. :)

The above works but it doesn't let you roll into the .prop_info (I probably should have mentioned that, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

You can use css for this, however this won't be supported for older versions of IE. And i'm also unsure if that is what you would want / need. But either way hope this helps.

change the following css for your .prop_info to:

```
.property .prop_info {
    width:274px;
    height:90px;
    background:url(/resources/images/backgrounds/agent-info-bg.jpg) top left no-repeat transparent;
    background: #0d70b2;
    position:absolute;
    left:136px;
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

then add this underneath:

```
.property:hover .prop_info {
    display: block;   
}
```

What this does is, that whenever you hover on a .property element the .prop_info element inside it will become visible. this however requires you to change the html layout so that the .prop_info is now inside the .property, Like so:

```
<div class="property" id="property{count}" style="display: block;">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/136x90/eeeeee/cccccc/&text=placeholder" /></a>
    <div  class="prop_info">
        <div id="property_info_content">[ content goes here ]</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For every element that would normally go outside of the screen, 5th or 4th.. I can't test right now because it all depends on how wide the website will be and if it will become adaptive or not.

but you could use the following css:

```
.property .prop_info:nth-child(4n+4) {
    left: -410px;
}
```

What this does is it gives every 4th element it finds a different left margin.. if you need it to be every 5th, just change the 4n+4 to 5n+5.

Hope this was of any help

Comment: This is really, really close but for some reason the :nth-child selector doesn't work. See http://jsfiddle.net/EQ2fG/43/ 

Been pulling my hair out and can't figure out why it won't work. Also tried :nth-of-type and no go. :/

Comment: Finally got it to work. Used jQuery to ensure it works in IE8. Simply used `.property:nth-child(7n+7)` div instead.